# String passed as function argument throws Uncaught TypeError of undefined

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I have the next code to replace accents from a string within a .js file:

```
var accents = /[áéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]/g;
var translate = {
    "á": "a", "é": "e", "í": "i", "ó": "o", "ú": "u", "ü": "u",
    "Á": "A", "É": "E", "Í": "I", "Ó": "O", "Ú": "U", "Ü": "U"
};

function removeAccents (stringArg) {

    console.log(stringArg);

    var returnStr = stringArg.replace(accents, function(match) {

       return translate[match];

    });

    return returnStr;
}
```

I bind the `removeAccents` function to a DOM text input via jQuery like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery(".strReplace").keyup(function (e) {

        var translatedStr = removeAccents(jQuery(this).val());
        // more code to execute

    });

});
```

But, as I type in the input field, program breaks with the next console output:

```
"M"
undefined
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined"

"Mó"
undefined
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined"
```

As you see by the output, the string value is passed to the `stringArg` variable, but that same variable is undefined when I try to manipulate it. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance for your reply(ies).

Comment: Where is the other `console.log()` call? I don't think you posted enough code. What statement generates the error?

Comment: [It seems to work as it stands](http://jsfiddle.net/NaKfY/4/)

Comment: @Pointy The function is called everytime a key is tipped to the input. If I type "Mónica" that would generate a sequence of outputs.

Comment: @Andy Yes, I know it does, actually it worked straight when I had all the javascript code within the HTML file. For maintenance reasons it was decided to separate the JS code and put it into a separate .js file. That's when it started to fail and throw this error. Thanks for taking the time to actually testing the code.

Comment: @AndresMauricio well for whatever reason the value being passed to the function is `undefined`. What elements on your page have that "strReplace" class?

Comment: @Pointy, just a regular input:

`<input class="strReplace" placeholder="Search by name" />`